# Можно ли на выборах проголосовать за одного кандидата?

Tags: обсуждение, выборы, голосование

Коллеги можно ли отдать свой голос за одного кандидата?

Если поподробней, то допустим я отдал первый голос за `N-го` кандидата и всё, а остальные два голоса я проигнорировал и никому не отдал, мой голос будет ли учтён? Или я обязан, всё же, остальные два голоса отдать за кого-то?

Comment: Можно, будет учтён

Comment: @NickVolynkin пожалуйста разместите ответ - ответом.

Comment: Вакантных позиций 2, если что. Так что стоит отдать как минимум 2 голоса, даже если вам нравится только 1 кандидат

Comment: @dIm0n, вопрос не в "нравиться или нет", я уже все три голоса отдал, просто стало интересно...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Можно, будет учтён – Nick Volynkin♦ 5 сен в 6:09