# Как отозвать голос на выборах?

Tags: поддержка, выборы, голосование

На выборах я отдал все свои 3 голоса. Но, узнав, что [могу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10814/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0#comment45863_10814) отдать меньше, решил отозвать один из голосов.

Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Отдать 3-й голос за того, кому дал 1-й голос. 3-й голос откатится. Теперь у кандидата 3-й голос, а 1-й свободен.
2. Потом отдать этому же человеку 1-й голос.
3. Теперь 3-й голос свободен и отозван. Останутся принятыми лишь 1-й и 2-й.

Таким образом можно отменить два голоса. Один голос в любом случае останется)

Comment: Ничего не понял. Просто выбрать любого пользователя и напротив него нажать по очереди на все три кнопки, всё.

Comment: Надо раставить падежные окончания, а то _дал 1 голос_, можно понять: _дал один голос,_ или _дал первый голос_.

Comment: @0xdb дал первый голос == дал 1-й голос

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Да, это так, вы правильно поняли.

Comment: @0xdb Я имел ввиду, что 1 == один, а 1-й == первый. Тут нечего путать ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Всё правильно, я так и попросил сделать, чтобы никто не путал. Или я вас не совсем понял, о чём вы напиасали в первом комментарии?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на правки ответа.